# Is it possible for PyTorch models to predict and learn at the same time?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

For investing, i am trying to make predictions. But every time loading datasets, fitting model from beginning.

Let i explain with one example:

I have Y currency value and X is the days.

X = [1,2,3,4]
Y = [2,4,6,8.8]

If i predict the next value (for X = 5), prediction result Y = 10.2

But next day. I get the real results from Central Bank and Y = 9.8 after i get the real result currently loading datasets from zero and fitting model again.

Is there any way to update only last value, just append the value to the model (for X = 5 append Y = 10.2)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for PyTorch models to predict and learn at the same time?

Of course. Learning with neural networks almost always involves making predictions. You predict something, then you calculate the error of the prediction, then you back-propagate the error to improve the parameters.

If your question is about sequences, that's kind of a separate thing. Perhaps these are relevant to your query:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_learning
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_learning